# JobScheduler Do multiple jobs in the same service Class

Tags: java, android-studio, android-jobscheduler

I'm doing so many jobs and I would like to know how to do it in 1 class. Or should I make many services classes to do each job without if condition?

I tried this, and I did many if statements to know which job is it to do only its job, but it's doing all if statements; even if I clicked 1 button, the job executes everything in the function without caring about the id == 1.

```
if (id == 1){
    if (mSocketDefaultService != null && mSocketDefaultService.connected()){
        mSocketDefaultService.emit("walker_started_1", "On my Way!");
        jobFinished(params, false);
    }else {
        if (mSocketDefaultService != null){
            mSocketDefaultService.connect();
        }
        jobFinished(params, true);
        Log.d(TAG, "ReDo Socket"+ params.getJobId());
        return;
    }
    jobFinished(params, false);

    Log.d(TAG, "Job finished"+ params.getJobId());
}
```

Comment: In general, prefer to have each job class do a single task

Comment: Oh, that's what I'm thinking but my fear is I don't know if this harms the device? if I did maybe 10 classes? its still service?

Comment: You might have a problem if you have more than a couple hundred...

Comment: Omg really? so I go now and do all my jobs with different classes JobSchedulers?

Comment: Last I checked, my app has just crossed ~180 Job classes, so yes

Comment: Thank you bro i reaaally! needed this confirmation <3

Comment: Note: There may be problems if you schedule more than 100 _instances_ at one time, but that's 100% unrelated to the total number of classes.

Comment: When i create a Thread should i do this? 
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
And If not its okay just to make the Thread and ignore it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205567/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-life-isnothingtome).